# Java android error in gradle with flutter

Tags: java, flutter

I installed Android studio and Flutter, I followed every passage of the website for the installation but when i try to compile the first example application it continue to show this error, but only when i try to buld it on an android device, because if I try to run it on chrome or edge it work.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Paolo\StudioProjects\myapp\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Paolo\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Not sure about the error because there is the missing code here, but I think the compiler are telling your that there is some error in your code with this line `> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60
`

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo It's strange because this code is the flutter example application that show up when you create a new flutter project

Comment: Take into consideration that the code may be a little bit old, in the last month flutter jump from version 1.* to version 2.2. This involved also the migration of android studio to version 4.2. I'm pretty sure that it is just an update of your system the problem. Try to run the following command `flutter run --flavor=client --target=lib/main.dart`

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo Thank you, i solved it by installing an older version of android studio.

Comment: I will add an answer to describe the solution here, later in this day